# How convert symbolic equation to solve in ode45?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve a differential equation like below:

```
%% Parameters Initialization
C    = 0.01;
gfi  = 0.2308;
gso  = 0.769;
Efi  = 17.333;
Eso  = 0;
km   = 0.842;
v12m = 5.85;
kn   = 4.4;
v12n = 9.667;
tauni = 3;

%% defining Functions
syms v n;
n_v_e = 1 / (1+exp((v12n-v)/kn));
m_v = 1 / (1+exp((v12m-v)/km));
gfi_v = gfi * m_v;
Dn = tauno*(n_v_e-n);
Ifi = gfi_v*(v-Efi);
Iso = gso*n*(v-Eso);
Dv = -1/C * (Ifi + Iso);

%% Solving ODE
v0 = -10;
n0 = 0.1;
te = 2000;

Dv = subs(Dv,'v','y(1)');
Dv = subs(Dv,'n','y(2)');
Dn = subs(Dn,'v','y(1)');
Dn = subs(Dn,'n','y(2)');

[t,V] = ode45(@(t,y)[Dv;Dn],[0 te],[v0;n0]);
```

the problem occurs right here at ode45 saying "Inputs must be floats, namely single or double."
I know the problem is due to symbols (n and v) but I don't know how to get rid of them!
I don't also want to write a seperate function and use it instead of [Dv;Dn].

Thank you for your help

Comment: `matlabFunction`! http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html

Comment: Or don't use symbolic math at all and just use [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) directly, which would be much faster.

Comment: I agree with @horchler, ignore symbolic maths and just create a standard function, much better approach.

Comment: Hey guys, I don't want to write any function at all.